# Global scope variable with React JS?

Tags: reactjs

In my  code, I create this function that initializes the tag of the ReactDOM.render() function :

```
var initialiserTag;

initialiserTag = function(tag){
  ReactDOM.render(<MyApp />, document.getElementById(tag));
}

export default initialiserTag;
```

Then I bundle my React code with webpack and put the bundle.js file at the end of my page:

```
{% block javascripts %}{{ parent() }}

    <!-- TODO
       Call initialiserTag('myTag') here
     -->

       <script src="{{ asset('bundles/app/bundle.js') }}"></script>                                
{% endblock %}
```

How can I call the initialiserTag() function from outside my bundle?

Comment: What's the purpose of putting this function in the global scope ? Just curious about that... :)

Comment: @ArnaudChrist Being able to call the same bundle multiple times on the same page but on different tags.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [expose-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/expose-loader)
for exposing some modules to global object.

Comment: I don't really understand how it works. All I have to do is to write `require("expose-loader?myApp!./myApp.js");` in my React code then `window.myApp.initialiserTag('myTag')` on the PHP page?

Comment: Did you tryed ?